# Where are the logins in my MVC C # program?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Has made the following guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

It automatically creates options for users to register and login. Where are they stored? Can not find it in the database. How do I check if someone is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

It stores the information in a [SQL Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) 4.0 database.

Answer (score 0):

By default the ASP.NET MVC X Web Application project template uses the [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) to store and manage the users which according to the article are stored in a SQL Compact 4.0 database. But if I recall correctly there isn't an officially supported membership provider for this database.

Sure you could write your own or use a third party solution such as:

http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/

However, if I download the code for the guide and check out the Web.config I notice that the SqlMembershipProvider is used and this is linked to the connection string called "ApplicationServices".

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
     ... />
```

Let's take a look at that connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated 
     Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
     User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Apparently its stored in a local database file called "aspnetdb.mdf" which is probably located in your web application's App_Data folder.

That is where you can find the user data. But is it actually used in this guide? Appears not, might just be a remnant of the default ASP.NET MVC Web Application project template.

The movie-related data is stored in an SQL Compact 4.0 database. A different connection string is used for it.

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

Also a local database file, but this time it is a different provider (SqlServerCe.4.0. instead of SqlClient).